# Carousel with numbers to auto rotate in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a project to have a carousel with numbers from 0-9 in it with the following code :

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

int numItems = 10;
var onSelectCard = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      darkTheme:
          ThemeData(platform: TargetPlatform.iOS, brightness: Brightness.dark),
      home: RotationScene(),
    );
  }
}
 
class RotationScene extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RotationSceneState createState() => _RotationSceneState();
}

class _RotationSceneState extends State<RotationScene> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'carrousel',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 2,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: SceneCardSelector(),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: [Color(0xff74ABE4), Color(0xffA892ED)],
          stops: [0, 1],
        )),
        child: MyScener(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CardData {
  Color color;
  double x, y, z, angle;
  final int idx;
  double alpha = 0;

  Color get lightColor {
    var val = HSVColor.fromColor(color);
    return val.withSaturation(.5).withValue(.8).toColor();
  }

  CardData(this.idx) {
    color = Colors.primaries[idx % Colors.primaries.length];
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
  }
}

class MyScener extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScenerState createState() => _MyScenerState();
}

class _MyScenerState extends State<MyScener> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _scaleController;
  List<CardData> cardData = [];
  double radio = 200.0;
  double radioStep = 0;
  bool isMousePressed = false;
  double _dragX = 0;
  double selectedAngle = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    cardData = List.generate(numItems, (index) => CardData(index)).toList();
    radioStep = (pi * 2) / numItems;

    _scaleController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
    _scaleController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));

    onSelectCard.addListener(() {
      var idx = onSelectCard.value;
      _dragX = 0;
      selectedAngle = -idx * radioStep;
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var initAngleOffset = pi / 2 + (-_dragX * .006);
    initAngleOffset += selectedAngle;
 
    // process positions.
    for (var i = 0; i < cardData.length; ++i) {
      var c = cardData[i];
      double ang = initAngleOffset + c.idx * radioStep;
      c.angle = ang + pi / 2;
      c.x = cos(ang) * radio;
//      c.y = sin(ang) * 10;
      c.z = sin(ang) * radio;
    }

    // sort in Z axis.
    cardData.sort((a, b) => a.z.compareTo(b.z));

    var list = cardData.map((vo) {
      var c = addCard(vo);
      var mt2 = Matrix4.identity();
      mt2.setEntry(3, 2, 0.001);
      mt2.translate(vo.x, vo.y, -vo.z);
      mt2.rotateY(vo.angle + pi);
      c = Transform(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        origin: Offset(0.0, -100 - _scaleController.value * 200.0),
        transform: mt2,
        child: c,
      );

      // depth of field... doesnt work on web.
//      var blur = .4 + ((1 - vo.z / radio) / 2) * 2;
//      c = BackdropFilter(
//        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: blur, sigmaY: blur),
//        child: c,
//      );

      return c;
    }).toList();

    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onPanDown: (e) {
        isMousePressed = true;
        setState(() {});
        _scaleController.animateTo(1,
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
      },
      onPanUpdate: (e) {
        _dragX += e.delta.dx;
        ///_dragX += 360;
        setState(() {});
      },
      onPanEnd: (e) {
        isMousePressed = false;
        _scaleController.animateTo(0,
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: list,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget addCard(CardData vo) {
    var alpha = ((1 - vo.z / radio) / 2) * .6;
    Widget c;
    c = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      width: 110,
      height: 120,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(alpha),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          stops: [0.1, .9],
          colors: [Color(0xFFFFE57F),Color(0xFFFFAB00)],
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.3 + alpha * .3),
              spreadRadius: 1,
              blurRadius: 12,
              offset: Offset(0, 2))
        ],
      ),
      child: Text('${vo.idx}',
    style: new TextStyle(
      fontSize: 50.0,
      color: Colors.black,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),),
    );
    return c;
  }
}

class SceneCardSelector extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: 80,
      child: Row(
        children: List.generate(
            numItems,
            (index) => Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 80,
                    child: OutlineButton(
                      child: Text(index.toString()),
                      onPressed: () => onSelectCard.value = index,
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need the following functions :

1. Auto rotate with speed variable (it should be triggered with start function)
2. Increase speed function to increase the rotation speed
3. Decrease speed function to decrease the rotation speed
4. stop function to stop at a given number (it should stop only when it reaches the card for the given number, should be seamless)
5. when stop function is triggered and rotation reaches the given number, the card size should increase and the background should change color.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a look at this package : carousel_slider.
I think it can help you with almost of your requirements

Comment: Thanks for reply, if you look at the code I posted, you will understand that carousel_slider can't be used here. if you think carousel_slider can be used please add an example here.